# How can I roll back a single change in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I made a change to a file in my mercurial project that I'd like to roll back, but I'd like to keep some changes that occurred subsequent to it:

```
Revision 1: Original
Revision 2: A change I made in error
Revision 3: A change I want to keep
```

I want to roll back ONLY the changes in Revision 2, leaving 1 and 3 applied, and create a new revision 4.  What is the most "Mercurial" way of doing that?

Note that yes, I could extract the reverse diff from revision 2 and apply it to my working copy as a patch, and commit that. I know. But I'd like to find some way that the tool directly supports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that if you view the changelog for the project (so that you can see all of the revisions), you can pick a single revision and use the backout command to undo it.

<sub>(I don't have anything at hand to check this, so it may be incorrect.)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You can use mq patches to edit your recent history as well. The following sequence of commands would do the trick:

```
hg qinit               # initialises a queue
hg qimport -r2:TIP     # moves revisions from 2 onwards into patch management
hg qpop -a             # unapplies patches, leaving your actual checkout at r1
hg qrm 2.diff          # deletes the r2 patch (forever)
hg qpush -a            # applies all remaining patches again (i.e. the r3 patch)
hg qfinish -a          # moves applied patches back into official repository history
```

This sort of thing is great for fixing up a mistake in your local repository, but since you're *changing history*, make sure you didn't push to someone else (or they didn't pull from you) the original version before you fixed it.

If I understand correctly, `hg backout` will instead commit a new patch which reverses the earlier change, thus keeping the change in your history. It's a safer option, but less nice if you make local mistakes often (like me).